# What is the object sold in this paragraph?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> Coupons allow instructors to promote their Udemy courses to students on and off the platform. Coupons are allowed only in promotional announcements and the Bonus Lecture. They cannot be used anywhere else on the Udemy platform, because once students enter a course, they expect a safe learning environment where they will not be “sold” to.

I cannot make sense whether in the above paragraph the learning environment is being sold to students or students are being sold to someone/somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

There is a  **to** which you are overlooking.

**....where they will not be sold *to*...**

Compare:

> I do not like to be spoken **to** in that manner.

To speak *to* someone.  To sell *to* someone.

A product can be sold.  (marketed)

A consumer can be sold. (convinced to purchase something)

A consumer can be sold **to**.  (subjected to a sales "pitch")

> There is no paved road to the dig site. It must be hiked *to*.
>
> The child was cranky and wanted to be sung to.

This is a class of verbs taking indirect objects.  I do not "speak you", rather I speak **to** you. The mother does not "sing her baby", rather she sings **to** her baby.  We do not "drive the stadium" we drive **to** the stadium. A person does not "sit a chair" but sits **on** a chair.

> A chair is for sitting **on**. A chair is made *to be sat on*.
>
> A house is for living in. It is designed *to be lived in*.
>
> The sliding-board in the playground is for sliding down. It is designed *to be slid down*.
>
> The coconut tree can be shimmied up.
>
> A narrow passageway in a cave can be squeezed through.

**....where they will not be sold *to*...** is thus the passive form of "where (we) will not sell to them", i.e. where we will not subject them to a sales pitch.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure I get what you mean by the starting sentence (There is ...),sorry.

Comment: In your quoted passage there is a second **to**.

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure there was a *first* **to** (second sentence of the OP's quote); or else it's the *third* **to** that you're discussing (the first two are in the first sentence of the OP's quote: "... **to** promote ... **to** students ...").

Comment: Right. It was cryptic. I had in my head the first **to** of the marked infinitive. I've removed the offending word.